# Should I return a value or throw an exception....?

Tags: c++, function, exception, return-value

I am writing a generic class of template `T`.

It has a member function as

```
T findElement (T data1)
{
    Tree<T> *tree=search (data1,TreeTop);
    if (tree==NULL) 
        cout<<"\n Element Not FOund \n "';
    else
        // Usefult Part Of Code Which Returns A Data Of Type T (Generic)
}
```

Now if the 1st condition is `true` should I throw an exception?

Will it tamper with my functions return type.
A little explanation on how exception works will be helpful.

Comment: Does `std::find` when it doesn't find an element in range throws an exception? No it doesn't, it returns something (i.e., range.end()) to signify that element doesn't exist in range.

Comment: so what should i return here...its generic data T...so i cant just return a 0..right.....?

Comment: Your shift key appears to be broken.

Comment: You should return something that signifies not found (e.g., T()).

Comment: If you want to return a value or a reference, the options are to return a sentinel value or raise an exception. You could also return an optional type that the caller can check. Alternatively, return a pointer or iterator that can be checked against something.

Comment: @40two, So if I have a tree containing `int` and I'm looking for a 0, how will I know whether I've found one?

Comment: exactlyy.....so what should be the return type in such cases....??

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast Very easy question. This `int` resides in a tree node you'll return a null node.

Comment: so i have to write return NULL; thats all....?

Comment: @PRP depends on how your tree is implemented. Return an empty node. How you signify an empty node that's up to you.

Comment: @40two, But `T()` is not a node, it's a `T`. Nothing was said about changing the return type to a node and returning an empty node.

Comment: i needed different opinions only based on other people' experience.....i goto learn a lot from the comments and answers....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not to throw an exception is a subjective question which depends on your situation and coding style.

In general most folk would say only throw an exception in unusual circumstances - so if you expect many searches searches to return no result then perhaps returning a special or specially formed element is a good idea, if this is something that should rarely or never happens under normal circumstances then an exception would be judged as appropriate by most developers.

Regarding return type: when a function throws there is no return type as the function never returns, instead the program resumes on the first line of the catch in the calling context.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options. Which one should be chosen depends entirely on the context.

1. Return `std::optional<T>` (or `boost::optional<T>`) when not finding anything can be part of the normal program flow.
2. Throw an exception if not finding anything indicates an exceptional situation caused by the program's environment which is neither your code's fault nor the result of bad input (e.g. if another thread has emptied the container in just the wrong moment or if the element was not put there due to memory running out).
3. `assert(false);`, terminating the program. Do this when not finding anything can only mean that your own code is wrong, so quick termination is the best thing which can possibly happen.